# PHP problem with array function - beginner

Tags: php

Hello I am just starting my adventure with coding and I have a question regarding that.

```
$element are numbers: 1,5,10,20.
```

`$liczba = tab[0] -` then `$liczba` value is `1`.

So if `$element>$liczba,` and `liczba` is `1, then tab[0]` - which is `1` shouldn't fit that criteria.

So why when I echo `$liczba` I get all elements with 1?

And second question. Why when I echo `$liczba` beyond [] brackets I get only 20 result, not 1(which shouldn't be here),5,10,20?

Answer is probably obvious, but I can't figure it out.

```
    <?php

$tab = array("1", "5", "10", "20");
$liczba = $tab[0];

foreach ($tab as $element)
{
    if($element>$liczba)
    $liczba = $element;
      echo $liczba; 
}
  echo $liczba; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to put braces {} after your if statement, meaning the comparison is unused so it is displaying all data.

```
$tab = array(1, 5, 10, 20);

foreach ($tab as $element) {
    if ($element > $tab[0]) {
        echo $element . ", ";
    }
}
```

I have also simplified your code by removing unnecessary variables.

Best practice:
I believe you should use a type that fits what you are comparing:

```
$tab = array("1", "5", "10", "20");
```

This will improve code readability.

```
$tab = array(1, 5, 10, 20);
```

Comment: Numeric comparisons will work just fine with strings or integers. PHP is a loosely typed language.

Comment: But still after I echo $element variable, outside foreach function I always get 20 Instead of 5.10.20?